# Generating data from eleven Gaussians, following a description from a paper

Tags: matlab, random-generation

I am reading the paper by Mika et al. [Kernel PCA and de-noising in feature space](https://alex.smola.org/papers/1999/MikSchSmoMuletal99.pdf) and in the 4th page I am reading the following

> In the first experiment (table 1), we generated a data set from eleven Gaussians in $R^{10}$ with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$ in each component, by selecting from each source 100 points as a training set and 33 points for a test set (centers of the Gaussians randomly chosen in                 $[-1,1]^{10}$).

Now I am trying to reproduce the above dataset in Matlab, but I am confused because it should be (as I understand it) like this

```
mu = zeros(10,1)
sigma = diag(0.2*ones(10,1)) % one of the 11 gaussians 
r = mnvrnd(mu,sigma,15)
```

This will give me a 15x10 matrix from which I'll randomly choose 100 for the train and 33 for the test (unique cases). Then I'll repeat for another case (a change in $\sigma$. In the end I'll have a matrix $X\in R^{133\times 11}$ for the train and and $R^{33\times 11}$ for the test.

However I am confused by the last sentence "*(centers of the Gaussians randomly chosen in $[-1,1]^{10}$).*". Does this mean that the Gaussians don't have mean **0**. Additionally, is the above reasoning correct?

Comment: Mean equal to zero and "random" centers is a contradictory statement. Maybe you should write to the authors of the paper for clarification? Otherwise, I'm afraid, it's a guessing game...

Comment: What's more, the passage doesn't specify the covariances.